# How to find the method in which an anonymous delegate was declared

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, delegates, clr

I'm trying to do perhaps some dubious caller analysis for logging. Regardless of if I want to actually do it in the end, I'd like to know if what I'm looking for is possible at all. If not, why not? Since it seems it *should* be possible to me.

Specifically:

```
    private static Action CreateAnonymousMethod()
    {
        MethodBase declaringMethod = new StackFrame(true).GetMethod();

        return delegate()
        {
            var myFrame = new StackFrame(true);

            // This is *this* anonymous method. I can figure out from the name
            // "<CreateAnonymousMethod>garbage" that when the compiler generated
            // it, it knew the answer, but from the MethodBase itself, I can find
            // no path back to declaringMethod. So this answer is incorrect, but
            // I feel like the data should be around here somewhere.
            MethodBase whatGoesHere = myFrame.GetMethod();

            Assert.AreEqual(declaringMethod, whatGoesHere);
        };
    }
```

My goal is I want more or less a 'Log' method that can walk up the stack and find the caller. I know the [[CallerMemberName]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) attributes and such, but there is no corresponding attribute for the declaring type of the caller's member, and the caller's member name is a mere string. I'd like to find a proper MemberInfo if possible.

So that led me to finding the caller's method via [StackFrame.GetMethod()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stackframe.getmethod(v=vs.110).aspx) however for nicer logging I'd like to detect if it's an anonymous delegate, and instead of or in addition to the anonymous delegate's [MemberInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.memberinfo(v=vs.110).aspx), use the declaring method's MemberInfo.

However, it seems I just can't 'get there from here.' The most frustrating bit is that I know the compiler knew at least while it was compiling, given the name of the anonymous delegate, but I can't seem to find a way back to the MemberInfo at runtime.

It seems like I want some invented property like MemberInfo.DeclaringMember which would for an anonymous method return the member in which it was declared. Saying that however I realize an anonymous method isn't even a CLR thing, and so by the time you're looking at reflection the information is just flat gone. So I was hoping in the [CompilerGeneratedAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.compilergeneratedattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) it would hold onto the original source MemberInfo and I could extract it from the attribute, but the attribute seems to leave no trace of it.

At this point I think my only option is the very brittle attempt to parse the anonymous method name (ha!) and then use that to somehow search for the corresponding MemberInfo.

Anyway, before I give up and go down that route and see how terrible it is, I thought I'd throw a hail mary out to the fine folks here at StackOverflow and see if there's any genius solution I'm missing, or, if my thought process is fundamentally flawed.

Comment: Side note: there is no real correlation between stack and declaration of delegate... Not very clear what you expect... Sample call to delegate may help to clarify why you expect stack frames to include creator of the delegate.

Comment: My point is that from within this delegate (or any delegate) a caller might call my 'Log' method. From there I need to use the stack to find the caller, which would be this delegate. From that point of view, I don't have 'declaringMethod.' Are you saying my sample should clarify that better? That someone might not understand the goal since I can just use 'declaringMethod' as I have it written?

Comment: Much of the detail is not persisted, at best you might be able to find a single method referencing your anonymous method by examining the IL of all other methods on the same type and its declaring type (MethodBase.GetMethodBody().GetILAsByteArray()) ... but probably more effort than it's worth.

Comment: @Keith - exactly - sample you have does not execute code in the delegate, so it is very confusing at which point you expect that `Assert.AreEqual(declaringMethod, whatGoesHere);` condition to run and be true. (I don't really know an answer but your question looks interesting enough to be better. If it would be me while waiting for answer I look into source of existing logging frameworks to see if/how it is done)

Comment: You can call a method at the beginning of each delegate that connects the delegate method (received via stack frame) and the declaring method (via `CallerMemberName` and the declaring type of the delegate method).